# NLS_CHARACTERSET WE8ISO8859P1 and UTF8 issues in Oracle

Tags: java, oracle

I am currently using a Database in oracle which has NLS_CHARACTERSET WE8ISO8859P1 so lets say I store a value in varchar2 field which is maž (accented character) so in database it gets stored as maå¾ . Now when I try to retrieve it with query select * from table where fieldValue = 'maž' it returns 0 rows, and then when i try to insert it again it gives me a constraint error saying value already exist.

How to overcome such situation. 
I am doing this via Java code

Comment: _"in database it gets stored as maå¾"_ How do you get that outpout? Can't this be a case of [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) ?

Comment: Could you try with `'ma\u017E'`? In order to exclude java source encoding problems or such. You can experiment with a SELECT getting the record field via its ID, and **dumping the bytes/code points**. As last resort maybe a PreparedStatement to fill in the field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch2charset.htm#g1009784

> Oracle Character Set Name: WE8ISO8859P1
>   Description: Western European 8-bit ISO 8859 Part 1
>   Region: WE (Western Europe)
>   **Number of Bits Used to Represent a Character: 8**

On the other hand, UTF-8 uses several bytes to store a symbol.

If your database uses WE8ISO8859P1 and the column type is from VARCHAR group (not NVARCHAR) and you're inserting a symbol which code > 255, this symbol will be transformed to WE8ISO8859P1 and some information will be lost.

To put it simply, if you're inserting UTF-8 into a db with single-byte character set, your data is lost.

The link above describes different scenarios how to tackle this issue.

You can also try Oracle `asciistr`/`unistr` functions, but in general it's not a good way to deal with such problems.

Comment: So I tried something like in java : String y = new String(x.getBytes() , Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
  System.out.println(y); It results in samething would it be safe to use it for doing a Select and checking if it exists.

Comment: @user958573 It depends on X. UTF8 has wider range of codes, so if you convert different symbols from UTF8 into ISO-8859-1 they may have the same value in the new charset

Comment: @user958573 But if all the symbols of X fit "ISO-8859-1" you can do that

Comment: So, it should work right lets say I am having X and Y which results in Z while storing in database, that would be anyways happening now. My final motive will be to have single Z record in database

Comment: @user958573 Actually, I don't know how Oracle converts characters which don't fit the db character set. Maybe it uses the same symbol each time.