# Reading signs like Č, Ć, Š, Đ, Ž, from Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle

I need to display some data from Oracle. But **Address name** contains some special character like "**Č, Ć, Š, Đ, Ž**" etc. These special characters are displayed properly in database, but when I try to get values from database using c#, I get this from **dataReader**:

- for Č, I get È
- for č, I get è
- for Ć, I get Æ
- for ć, I get æ
- for Ž, I get \u008e
- for ž, I get \u009e
- for š, I get \u009a

What I need to do to get from dataReader the same value like value from database? I didn't find the answer on google yesterday, so I decided to ask here.

Someone please help.

I'm using C# and Visual Studio 2015. I just need to select rows from base, I'm not able to update or insert values. This is my code:

```
private OracleConnection _connection;
private OracleCommand _command;

public List<Address> GetAddressList()
{
    string query = "SELECT id, name FROM address";

    _command = new OracleCommand(query, _connection);
    OracleDataReader dataReader = _command.ExecuteReader();

    List<Address> addressList = new new List<Address>();

    while (dataReader.Read())
    {
        Address address = new Address
        {
            id = dataReader["id"].ToString(),
            Name = dataReader["name"].ToString()
        };

        addressList.Add(address);
    }

    dataReader.Close();

    return addressList;
}
```

Comment: Which provide do you use? (e.g. ODP.NET , ODP.NET Managed Driver, OraOLEDB). What is your `NLS_LANG` value?

Comment: I'm using ODP.NET Managed Driver, and NLS_LANG value is American_America.WE8ISO8859P1

Comment: You database character set is `WE8ISO8859P1`. This character set does not support characters like Č, Ž, š, see [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1). Unless you use `NCHAR` data type, resp. migrate your database character set to something else you cannot insert or select such characters.

Answer (score 0):

This question is basically the same: [Trouble using/displaying special characters from Oracle db in .Net app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222529/trouble-using-displaying-special-characters-from-oracle-db-in-net-app)

You have some data stored in database and You need to display them. There are several things that must be checked:

> 1) Have I been using the right encoding during **save**?
>
> 2) Are the information **stored** in the database in readable form (correct encoding codec)?
>
> 3) Am I using correct encoding during data **receive** (decoding)?

It is important to check all 3 things, as You might encode them good, but Oracle (or any DB) will just convert them to final encoding, which might not support the characters. Also when You will query this against DB, it will return in the set encoding and You will be converting it to some final form.

**EDIT:**

As the database is storing all the characters in this encoding: `WE8ISO8859P1`, I would recommend You to read other StackOverflow answer: 
 - [NLS_CHARACTERSET WE8ISO8859P1 and UTF8 issues in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27296249/nls-characterset-we8iso8859p1-and-utf8-issues-in-oracle)

Problem is that the characters are stored as 1 byte (8 bits) only and the encoding is for `American_America`, You will be unable to store such characters as 'ž' 'č' or others.

Solution would be to change **Encoding** of the `Table` and/or better for whole `Database`.

**EDIT #2** as [Wernfried Domscheit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3027266/wernfried-domscheit) stated:

*You database character set is `WE8ISO8859P1`. This character set does not support characters like Č, Ž, š, see [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1). Unless you use `NCHAR` data type, resp. migrate your database character set to something else you cannot insert or select such characters.*

Comment: - Thanks a lot for helping, but I still not resolved this. I've just updated my post. I'm not able to do any modification in database, only I can do is to use Select. So, I wonder is there any way to write c# code to return value from database that will contains these special characters? If there is no way, I'm going to use combination find-replace (find È, replace with Č)

Comment: Could You run this query `SELECT * FROM nls_database_parameters WHERE parameter='NLS_CHARACTERSET';` ?

Comment: Yes, and I get this value 'WE8ISO8859P1'

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not able to make any modification on Database. So I'm going to change my C# code to this `dataReader["name"].ToString().Replace("È", "Č").Replace("Æ", "Ć")...etc`. Once again, thanks a lot for helping.