# json JSON_ELEMENT_T oracle pl CHARACTER SET parse ISO88591

Tags: json, oracle, plsql

I am  parsing JSON in Oracle database 12.2.1. It works fine with utf8 characters but with characters like 'tilde' (for example é,ó) it doesn't work and I get `ORA-40441 JSON Syntax` error. My database nls is `NLS_CHARACTERSET=WE8ISO8859P1`. This is the code. Thank you.

```
DECLARE
 vjeData          JSON_ELEMENT_T;
BEGIN
  vjeData := JSON_ELEMENT_T.parse(' { "color": "CANCIÓN" } ');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('vjeData ' || vjeData.TO_STRING);
END;'
```

Updated

I set my windows client system variable NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1 and i get the same error

Comment: Perhaps this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27296249/nls-characterset-we8iso8859p1-and-utf8-issues-in-oracle may help.

Answer (score 0):

From oracle docs:

> Static function parse accepts an instance of type VARCHAR2, CLOB, or
>   BLOB as argument, which it parses as JSON text to return an instance
>   of type JSON_ELEMENT_T, JSON_OBJECT_T, or JSON_ARRAY_T. For BLOB, you
>   can only use data that has encoding UTF-8. An error is raised if the
>   parse input is not well-formed JSON data or the encoding is not UTF-8.

That means, if you pass a varchar2, it has to be encoded with the database character set. So you have to make sure the NLS_LANG setting at your client matches the character set encoding which is actually used (client side).

If you want to use UTF8 and want to prevent the encoding being changed because of the client NSL_LANG differs from the database character set, you need to provide it as a BLOB.

Comment: `BLOB` might be an overkill. Usually `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` (typically `AL16UTF16`) provides full unicode support, i.e. you could use `NVARCHAR2`, resp. `NCLOB`

Comment: Than you for your help, I set my windows client system variable NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1 and i get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This is an error reported by oracle,JSON Error ORA-40474 (Doc ID 2363165.1), the solution:

SOLUTION
Character set should be UTF8 DB.

https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2363165_1.html